# How do I know who is using my COM port and terminate it

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to open a serial port using below command and running into `WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')` error,how do I figure out who is using this port now and terminate it via commandline?

CODE:

```
mport serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
self.ser = serial.Serial(self.port, baud_rate, timeout=timeout)
........
```

Error:-

```
could not open port 'COM77': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

Comment: Try [handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle), e.g. `handle -a Serial`. Or use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer) to find the handle. You may also need [WinObj](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/winobj) to map the NT serial device to "COM77". It should be a symbolic link in the `\Global??` directory.

Comment: the links are not working

Comment: I swear they were working yesterday, and that's the first Google hit I get for "sysinternals handle". Anyway, try these links instead: [handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655), [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), [winobj](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657).

Comment: any of these have command line utilities that I can use to identify the process using the COMport and terminate?

Comment: I used Handle as below ,how to know which process is using `COM77 ``X:\scripts\loadbuild\Handle>handle.exe /accepteula -a Serial

Nthandle v4.1 - Handle viewer
Copyright (C) 1997-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

QPSTServer.exe     pid: 4328   type: Key            1AC: HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM
QPSTServer.exe     pid: 4328   type: Key            324: HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM
QPSTServer.exe     pid: 4328   type: Key            424: HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM
`

Comment: Those aren't file handles for a serial device. Check WinObj in the `\Global??` directory to see to which NT device "COM77" is linked. Then search for a handle to that device name.